# how to keep selected value in dropdown after submit in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i submitted for get class wise subject list i get class wise list but selected class reset after submit form..Please help me about this.[here is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C727r.png)

and here is my selected code..

```
<select name="class_id" class="form-control"  id="class_id">
    <option value="">{{trans('student_lang.student_select_class') }}</option>
    @foreach($class as $classes)
    <option value="{{$classes->id}}">{{$classes->title}}</option>
    @endforeach                                     
</select>                                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($class as $classes)
   <option value="{{ $classes->id }}" @if($classes->id==old('class_id')) selected @endif>{{ $classes->title }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Or

```
@foreach($class as $classes)
   <option value="{{ $classes->id }}" @if($classes->id==\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::old('class_id')) selected @endif>{{ $classes->title }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Just match the selected id.

```
<select name="class_id" class="form-control"  id="class_id">
    <option value="">{{trans('student_lang.student_select_class') }}</option>
    @foreach($class as $classes)
    <option value="{{$classes->id}}" {{($classes->id == $user->id) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$classes->title}}</option>
    @endforeach                                     
</select>
```

try to use old()

```
<option value="{{$classes->id}}" {{($classes->id == old('class_id')) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$classes->title}}</option>
```

Comment: its not working.. after form submission i got my expected list but selected value reset..

Comment: try to use old('class_id')

Answer (score 1):

- Parse from **Query String**:

```
<option value="{{ $classes->id }}" {{ request()->get("class_id") == $classes->id  ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $classes->title }}</option>
```

- After redirecting back causing failure of request validation, use **old()** function:

```
<option value="{{ $classes->id }}" {{ old("class_id") == $classes->id ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $classes->title }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
First form Facade add then after use

```
      {!! Form::select('class_id',$class,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer with an explenation of your code?